# PHP 7 - ReflectionParameter::getType() and gettype() not returning the same for certain types

Tags: php, php-7.4

I have a series of classes for a restful web service which should run some business logic by accepting a method taken from the URI and a JSON from input, in this form:

```
URI: https://my-ws.local/person/dosomething

Payload:

    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 30,
        "customer": true,
        "interests": ["movies", "rumba", "soccer"]
    }
```

Before running into any business logic I want to do some method availability and parameters checking so I can quickly return a *400ish error* if any inconsistence was found at this stage.

As I might end up with so many classes and methods, I thought it would be a nice idea to abstract this in sort of *an entry point method* -let's call it **run()**- which will then validate and call the proper business logic methods.

**run()** would use the reflection class in order to take the functions' signature as a parameter count and type validation rule and then make the proper call if everything was ok.

For simplicity, let's bundle all this together in a single mockup class like the following:

```
class Person
{
 public function run(string $method, string $args){

  // Load json into an array.
  $arrArgs = json_decode($args, true);

  // Initialize a valid arguments array.
  $validArgs = array();

  // Check if method parameters are fulfilled.
  $reflector = new ReflectionClass($this);
  foreach ($reflector->getMethod($method)->getParameters() as $param){

   // Parameter missing, cannot continue
   if(!array_key_exists($param->name, $arrArgs))
   {
    die("400 Bad Request, parameters missing!");
   }

   // Check if parameter is the correct type.
   if($param->getType() <> gettype($arrArgs[$param->name])){
    die("400 Bad Request, type mismatch!");
   }

    // Parameter OK, add it to the valid arguments array.
    $validArgs[$param->name] = $arrArgs[$param->name];

  }
  // Checks passed, call the method.
  call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $validArgs);
 }

 private function doSomething(string $name, int $age, bool $customer, array $interests)
 {
  echo 'Hi, ' . $name . '. You are ' . $age . ' years old, you are ' . ($customer ? "" : "not ") . 'a customer and your interests include ' . implode(", ", $interests) .'!';
 }
}
```

So roughly, the call would then be sort of:

```
$myPerson = new Person();

$json = '
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 30,
        "customer": true,
        "interests": ["movies", "rumba", "soccer"]
    }
';

$myPerson->run('doSomething', $json);
```

Well, I got this working with strings and arrays, but it looks like **ReflectionParameter::getType()** and **gettype()** are not returning the same results for a given type, as I'm getting, respectively:

```
string - string // OK
int - integer // Type mismatch
bool - boolean // Type mismatch
array - array // OK
```

I didn't even test it with the remaining types.

¿Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Those name mappings look pretty trivial, but note that you'll run into problems with more complicated types like unions in newer versions of PHP.

Comment: The `__toString()` is deprecated as of PHP 7.1, which you are implicitly calling in your comparison. Check out the first example [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.gettype.php) which has an extra `getName` call that should get what you are looking for.

Comment: As @IMSoP mentioned, with more complex types you might need to start looking into [ReflectionType](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectiontype.php) with subclasses, and I don't know if `gettype` will be expanded beyond strings for debugging sake.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Expanding `gettype` wouldn't help for union types - given the value "hello", there is no meaningful function that would know to return "string|int", "string|Foo", etc. I seem to remember discussion of adding a method to ReflectionType to check if it would accept a particular value, but I'm not sure if anyone got around to implementing it. It might be worth checking libraries like "Better Reflection" as well.

Comment: As you are building this thing, overall it seems totally sane, but I would recommend safe-listing the methods that you want to allow this magic invocation on. This could be just a method called `getAllowedMethods()`, or my preference, a simple custom Attribute you invent such as `#ApiCallable`.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP, as the coffee starts kicking in that totally makes sense!

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for your comments. I'm pretty aware of the tradeoffs for a magic method which calls the others so yes, some safety measures should be in place. Anyway, it looks like my intentions are good but I better give this a second thought and may be let the target methods handle their own stuff.

Comment: @IMSoP I completely see your point. I first thought of keeping the methods picky so no chance of weird new types but unions would eventually break my logic anyway. Also, not quite sure about gettype(). I'm giving this a second thought. Thanks!